# Dojo AMD loader not working in Domino 9.0

Tags: dojo, lotus-domino, js-amd

When I put this on my Form (not XPage):

```
<script src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

calls like this:

```
require(["dojox/validate/web"], function(validate) {
    validate.isEmailAddress(someAddress);
});
```

fail with error (this error is from Opera 12.15):

> Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: require

I checked with Chrome network panel that dojo.js is loaded and tried also with IE10.

If I use:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

everything works fine. Does Domino have some kind of special version of Dojo 1.8 which does not support AMD loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the `<script>` tag syntax shown in [Dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/loader/amd.html):

```
<script data-dojo-config="async:1" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

The `<script>` tag syntax in my question is a copy paste from [this Dojo sample](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/validation/demo/htmlcheck.php). Interestingly it does not work in Domino. Maybe it requires Dojo 1.8.3.