# How to implement modern Dojo(AMD) in IBM Notes 9.0.1 to load dojo files Asynchronously

Tags: dojo, xpages, amd, lotus-notes

The Dojo version upgrated as 1.8.3 in IBM Notes 9.0.1 from Dojo 1.6 in Lotus 8.5.3.
I keep hear the word Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) in Dojo and it has been 
indrouced since Dojo 1.7. But still i dont know how to implement AMD in Xpages to take advantage of 
modern dojo.

I tried to set dojo properties in xsp properties as below. 
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig=async:true

But its not help. IBM 9 use existing Synchrous mode to downlaod the dojo script library

Is there way to implement AMD in IBM 9.0.1 to get full advantage of modern dojo.

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711354/dojo-amd-loader-not-working-in-domino-9-0

Comment: No. I need to implement this on X-pages not in traditional notes design element(forms). Since Dojo 1.8.3 default library in IBM 9.0.1 why need to refer by script Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Mahendran,

Can you try to incorporate the following, we are able to load the same in the Mobile application, the link below link may help you.

```
<script src="../dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  require([
    "dojox/mobile",
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojox/mobile/compat"
  ]);
</script>
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/mo-dojo-mobile-performance/index.html?ca=dat

Comment: Can you suggest me how to approach in xpages of Domino 9.0.1. Able to enable dojoConfig="async:true" using Xsp Properties. Even though set synchronous still Xpages refer old syntax. Ex. Instead of require it refer dojo.require. But dojo global object is deprecated in modern dojo. Hence, enable async:true, break entire xpage application to load. Please suggest me if you have any concern